# Using previous context in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got a lot of this in my code:

```
var self = this;
let foob = _.filter(data, function(d) { return d.bar == self.do(); });
```

Is there a way to avoid having to declare a new variable to reference a context?

Comment: The arrow function notation gives you a lexical this. _.filter(data, d => d.bar === this.do());

Comment: Yes, use an arrow function  `d => ...` as the filter and replace `self` with `this`. Arrow functions lexically bind the `this` variable (= outer block's this), which is a exactly what you want.